# Email of Twitter User in Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter-oauth

Can twitter4j get the email of twitter users authorizing an application/web site.

I was able to get the screen name as below:

```
User user = twitter.showUser(id);
String screenName = user.getScreenName();
```

How about the email? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the user details using the below API: http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?user_id=YOUR_USER_ID

Twitter says it doesn't provide any API for email retrieval. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6718

Comment: The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Also you need to update links.

Comment: You can get email address once your twitter application is whitelisted. You can request access with this form: https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform