# Get a User's email address from Twitter (Android)

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

How can i get email address of a user via twitter API? I'm using Twitter4j for Sign in with twitter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Email of Twitter User in Twitter4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083145/email-of-twitter-user-in-twitter4j)

Comment: Also, see this link: https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/request-email

Comment: @DanielNugent..your link is helpful but which method should i use in case of twitter4j?

Comment: Also, for the first link it gives me XML doc error when i enter my username @DanielNugent

Comment: Take a look at this: https://twittercommunity.com/t/easy-way-of-get-users-twitterid-and-email/17099

Comment: @DanielNugent...yes there is a way using class TwitterAuthClient. However, that's what the problem is ! I'm not using the Fabric and Core Twitter API because i wasn't able to successfully import its library in my gradle build file. Hence i switched to twitter4j. But for twitter4j there is no way to get email !!! Weird :\

Comment: do you have a session? login to your app by twitter, if not then you cant get the email adress.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be work
please Use following code in your request call back result

```
 TwitterloginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                session = result.data;

                AccountService ac = Twitter.getApiClient(result.data).getAccountService();
                ac.verifyCredentials(true, true, new Callback<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User> result) {

                        String imageUrl = result.data.profileImageUrl;
                        String email = result.data.email;
                        String Name = result.data.name;
                        long userid = result.data.id;
                        String username = result.data.screenName;

                        System.out.println(imageUrl);
                        System.out.println("EMAIL:" + email);
                        System.out.println("Name:" + Name);
                        System.out.println("ID:" + userid);
                        System.out.println("Username:" + username);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

check these links

https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/installation

https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/log-in-with-twitter

Write below code after successful login

```
TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
   @Override
    public void success(Result<String> result) {
    // Do something with the result, which provides the email address
}

@Override
public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
  // Do something on failure
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all make sure you activated `Request email addresses from users` in your twitter app `Permissions` section

[image]

---

**then follow Twitter Documentation steps**:

**1.** [Installation process](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/installation): which ***simply imports*** the sdk package of twitter

> and i'm using only the core package

```java
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
```

Initialize Twitter Kit on your Activity `onCreate` method

```java
Twitter.initialize(this);
```

Add your App id and secret to `strings.xml` file

```html
<string android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY">XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
<string android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET">XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
```

---

**2.** [Add the Button](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/log-in-with-twitter):

```html
<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
     android:id="@+id/twitter_connect"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

> HINT: you can use a custom button just [follow this simple answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47815966/4846859)

```java
private TwitterLoginButton twitterBtn;
```

...

```java
twitterBtn = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_connect);
twitterBtn.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
        // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
        // which is do the callback from twitter to get the Email
        TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
        TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
        String token = authToken.token;
        String secret = authToken.secret;

        TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
        authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<String> result) {
                // Do something with the result, which provides the email address
                // the email is saved in the result variable 'result.data'
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Email" + result.data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                // Do something on failure
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
        // Do something on failure
    }
});
```

Next, pass the result of the authentication Activity back to the button:

```java
// Pass the activity result to the login button.
twitterBtn.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

**like so:**

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result to the login button.
    twitterBtn.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Twitter sdk helps you to provide the email, You just need to provide the permission requesting for email. Twitter sdk will check for the visibility of the email on your twitter account,If it has the permission it will provide you the Email else we need to handle the if it doesn't send's the email.

```
client.requestEmail(twitterSession, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<String> result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Twitter success email : " + result.data);
            email = result.data;
            if (email == null){

            }else {
            Log.d(TAG,"Email"+ email);  
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Twitter failed  email : " + exception);
        }
    });
```

Comment: TwitterAuthClient client =  new TwitterAuthClient();

Comment: plz add little explanation too

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Here Twitter sdk helps you to provide the email, You just need to provide the permission requesting for email. Twitter sdk will check for the visibility of the email on your twitter account,If it has the permission it will provide you the Email else we need to handle the if it doesn't send's the email.

Answer (score 0):

**To Get Twitter Email and Profile Image URL , username, id you to call requestEmail method.**

Also You to **allow request email in your developer account** of twitter. See below images.

[image: Retrieve Email id on twitter login]

**Use Below code to Get user details.**

```
    btnTwitterLogin.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
            TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
            TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
            authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<String> result) {
                    String email =result.data;
                    String token = authToken.token;
                    String secret = authToken.secret;
                    String username = session.getUserName();
                    long userId = session.getUserId();
                    Log.e("neem", "success: \n Token =>  " + token + "\n Secret: " + secret + " \n Username: " + username + "\n Userid: " + userId+" \n Email: "+email);

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                    Log.e("neem", "failure: "+exception.getMessage() );
                }
            });
            TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient(result.data).getAccountService().verifyCredentials(false,true,false).enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<User> userResult) {
                    try {

                        String imageUrl = userResult.data.profileImageUrl;
                        String username = userResult.data.screenName;
                        Log.e("neem", "acount services: imageurl: "+imageUrl+"\n username: "+username );

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            ShowToast(mcontext, "Login failed due to: \n "+exception.getMessage());
        }
    });
```