# How to get the email of current logged in user from twitter in android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I'm Integrating Twitter into my application using the Twitter 4j library. I'm trying to extract the email of the currently logged in user. Is there any way that I can take the email address of the user without having to prompt them?

I've checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395945/how-to-get-user-information-from-twitter-in-android-app), but it doesn't quite explain how to achieve what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the email from an user so easily, if you check the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/request-email) you need to be **whitelisted by Twitter**. If you aren't, you can't get the email, twitter4j doesn't provide any method to achieve that.
  And, possible duplicate:

- [Get a User's email address from Twitter (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137897/get-a-users-email-address-from-twitter-android)
- [Email of Twitter User in Twitter4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083145/email-of-twitter-user-in-twitter4j)